# Двумерный массив char

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать. Мне нужен массив Char Field[20][20] заполненные символами из файла.

Я сделал вот такую функцию:

```
void Spiel::readFile(std::string fileName) {
    std::ifstream file(fileName.c_str());
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << fileName << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string line;
    int a = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (a == 21)
            break;
        std::getline(file, line);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
            if (line[i] == std::string::npos) {
                Field[a][i] = '#';
            }
            else {
                Field[a][i] = line[i];
            }
        }
        a++;
        // weiter machen if, wenn Field [i][j] == "B", bx = i, by = j
    }
    std::cerr << "Done" << std::endl;
} 



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Spiel spiel;
    spiel.readFile(std::string(argv[1]));
};
```

По gdb print Field или print line выдает непонятные числа и знаки, но ни как не буквы которые стоят в считываемом файле. Не могу понять что не так

Comment: Вы бы воспользовались отладчиком, было бы скорее.

Comment: каким отладчиком ?

Comment: Какой-то странный алгоритм заполнения массива... Начиная с `while(true) { if(a==21) ...`.  Читая этот мозголомный код сложно уловить суть.

Comment: @PinkTux замысел был таков, что по строчке все считаются буквы из файла и сохраняются в Field. Переменная а считает количество строк.  Когда было сосчитано 20 строк, то  break

Comment: @Владимир: Любым, собственно. Обычно в комплекте с компилятором идёт отладчик.

Comment: @VladD если я правильно понял, то gdb имеется ввиду. Я им и проверял. Но не пойму почему он print line выдает кучу символов, за место содержания файла

Comment: @Владимир, а упростить до `while( a <= 21 )` или `for` - не? Откуда в файле "с символами" возьмётся `std::string::npos`? (тем более что это никак не один символ, а `size_t`, и сравнивать с ним `line[i]` как минимум странно, как максимум говорит об ошибке в алгоритме...) Что жекасается попадающего в `line`,то ко всему окружающему коду это вряд ли имеет отношение. Упростите до голого чтения из файла (`int main() { ... std::getline(...); return 0; }`) и смотрите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один вопрос: что вы подразумевали под этой строкой `line[i] == std::string::npos` ? Если я правильно понял, если строка короче 20 символов, то вы ее добиваете решетками, я прав?

В целом сразу бросается в глаза, что вы заполняете массив на 20 строк, но читаете вы 21 раз, да и вообще, зачем мучаться с `while(true)`, если по факту все равно у вас цикл с заранее известным количеством шагов, надо заменить на `for` .

Теперь, длину строки имеет смысл проверять как `i >= line.length()` .

В итоге получается примерно так:

```
void Spiel::readFile(std::string fileName) {
    std::ifstream file(fileName.c_str());
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << fileName << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string line;
    for(int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
        std::getline(file, line);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
            if (i >= line.length()) {
                Field[a][i] = '#';
            }
            else {
                Field[a][i] = line[i];
            }
        }
    }
    std::cerr << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

Я проверил этот код на файле с этой самой функцией, получилось так:

```
#include <iostream>#
#include <string>###
#include <fstream>##
####################
void readFile(std::s
    char Field[20][2
    std::ifstream fi
    if (!file.is_ope
        std::cerr <<
        exit(1);####
    }###############
    std::string line
    int a = 0;######
    while (true) {##
        if (a == 21)
            break;##
        std::getline
        for (int i =
            if (line
                Fiel
```